# Exclude System Hardlinks from File.Copy

Tags: c#, user-profile, file-copying, hardlink

So my problem is that I want to export my user account.
But inside `C:\%user%\AppData\Local\` are `System Hardlinks` e.g.: `Application Data` which I obviously have no right to use them.

Is there a way to exclude those `System Hardlinks` from the copying process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the issue with `Exception handling`, doing it this `way`:

```
FileInfo[] sourceFiles = null;

            try {

                sourceFiles = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath).GetFiles();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

                WriteLog(LogPath, ex + "");                                 
                return;
            }
```

Since I'm a bit new to `exception handling`, I couldn't work it out for the first few hours on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with hard links, but this might help you

```
foreach (var dir in new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local").GetDirectories())
{
    if (dir.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReparsePoint))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dir.Name + " is symbolic, skip it");
    }
    else
    {
        //do your copy here
    }
}
```